# WebLogic Server IS starting and functional in Eclipse Galileo yet I get several errors on startup

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I'm able to start WebLogic Server 11gR1 PatchSet 2 on my local machine and my web application is accessible after starting up WLS, yet I'm getting errors in my Eclipse Galileo Error Log on startup.  Here's the messages I'm getting in ascending order:

- Started WebLogic Server Monitor [mydomain@localhost:7001, Version:10.3.3.0]
- Unable to find tools.jar within Java VM associated with target WebLogic runtime; features dependent on tools.jar may not function
- The server cannot be launched within timeout.
- Server Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 PatchSet 2 at localhost was unable to start within 480 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

I've increased the timeout setting to 480 seconds (8 minutes) and one would think that's sufficient enough time for the startup.

I am able to run my web application successfully and output is generated on the Console as well so the last three error messages in the bullets above aren't show stoppers.

Wondering if any of you have run across these errors and how you went about to resolve them.

Comment: @Viccari: OS=Windows XP Pro | JVM=1.6.0_27

Comment: The symptom of not finding tools.jar is normally associated with Weblogic running on a JRE, instead of a JDK. Please make sure it is associated with a JDK (by setting JAVA_HOME to point to the JDK). Is this the case?

Comment: @Viccari - I do have the JAVA_HOME set in my environment variables.  Maybe the path is wrong?  It's set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre

Comment: That can be the cause. Please change it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27`, restart WebLogic and see what happens.

Comment: Nope - still getting the error messages popping up...i'll keep trying and maybe someday get this resolved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to latest version of Eclipse Java EE (Indigo SR2 for win32) and was able to launch it with no issues.